# ng-reflect-value is truncated

Tags: angular

I am using **ngModel** for MatSelectionList Binding. the variable i am assignning to ngModel have the data but when i checked Value of Options it truncates the **Id** after 30Char so the data from Model doesnot match and the checkbox is not binding.

[image]

you can have look the value in highlighted Area it is only part of value i have added and the rest is truncated. Full value you can see in below image Which is Array i have added in ngModel.

In my Database i have max-length=36 and value only Accepts maximum 30. and i don't want to change the Max-length in my Database.

[image]

i have found this Github Repository: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28786

but it has been no help can anyone help me find solution to my problem?

[image]

my ng-reflect model has no value init could it be the reason?

Comment: `ng-reflect-value` is not the same as `value`, it's just there for debugging purpose. Your model is bound to the `value` property on `MatListOption`, not to `ng-reflect-value`. Whatever the value you see in `ng-reflect-value` that shouldn't affect the binding in any way.

Comment: Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhaazu) where everything seems to be working just fine.

Comment: thank you for quick answer @lbsn. i have checked my code again it seems exactly  it is in stackblitz still not eorking but i think i will check again if i have missed something.

Comment: hello @lbsn i have updated question and added new image can you have a look ? i checked again everything is exactly like stalkblitz and it's working there but not in my code.

Comment: As I said `ng-reflect-*` attributes are for debugging purpose so the problem is not that `ng-reflect-model` itself is `undefined`. But that means that your model is `undefined` and __this__ could be the problem. So first of all check your model, see if the binding works as expected. Then for any further help you should share some of your code.